# Multiple Variable declaration in Data Factory using a JSON

Tags: json, azure, azure-data-factory

I'm designing some pipelines in Azure Data Factory, that I want to be as generic as possible, since they will be used by different data types and for different use cases. I am fairly new to Data Factory.

I basically have a JSON where I have declared all the variables to be used in the pipeline that will both control what the pipeline does (through IF conditions) and also stuff like where he should get the files, where to write them, etc. I could just use the output of the lookup activity that reads the JSON, but the JSON is rather complex and I'll end up having stuff like @activity('Lookup').output.value[0].data_type[0].file[0].file_curation[0].destination_folder, which I want to avoid since anyone new that looks at this would basically need to use a JSON as a dictionary to understand what is going on on the pipeline.

Is there any way I can set multiple variables (not an array, actual separate variables) without having dozens of Set Variable activities in my pipeline? (I wouldn't mind having them, just not on my main pipeline that I want to keep clean). Maybe a script that takes in the JSON and outputs them to the pipeline or something.

Any help is appreciated, thank you

Comment: Is this JSON being passed in as a pipeline parameter or just stored in a known location? Either way, a JSON config file is an interesting idea, especially considering the ADF is JSON itself - so a meta-JSON file?

Comment: The JSON is stored in a BLOB in Azure yes. Well I'm developing in the graphical interface (Activity drag and drop and all), but yeah something like that. If Data Factory's Set Variable Activity could set several variables at once that would solve all my problems, but unfortunately it does not...